# find maximum score by each player with each team in cricket world cup 2023

Tags: sql, mysql, greatest-n-per-group

Find maximum score  by each player with each team

```
select distinct team_innings,batsman_name ,max(runs) 
from batting_summary
group by team_innings,batsman_name
order by max(runs) desc
limit 5;
```

I want, one player from each team who score maximum

Comment: Don't tag multiple RDBMS (Oracle, MySQL, SQLite). Just tag the one you are interested in. Please [edit] your question and include a [MRE] with: which one RDBMS you are using; the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for your sample data (as text we can copy-paste, not images); and the expected output for that sample data.

Comment: See the linked duplicate - you want something like `WITH ranked_runs AS (SELECT b.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY batsman_name ORDER BY runs DESC) AS rn FROM batting_summary AS b ) SELECT * FROM ranked_runs WHERE rn = 1;`

Comment: @MT0 still its not working

Comment: "its not working" is not a constructive statement as it does not tell us what is not working or what the error is. You have not provided any sample data or any expected output (see my first comment) so its difficult to see how we can assist if we cannot see the problem and don't know what a "correct" solution looks like.